# Python vs JavaScript - UTC time from ordinal time

Tags: javascript, python, time, timezone, python-datetime

In Python:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1329429600)
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 17, 0, 0)
```

In JavaScript:

```
>>> (new Date(1329429600000)).toUTCString()
"Thu, 16 Feb 2012 22:00:00 GMT"
```

If what I'm looking for is UTC\GMT, which of the two is correct?
How can I fix the other one?

Comment: Javascript is "correct".
Python is showing you datetime according to your machine's timezone. And actually it is correct too, cause you don't ask it to show UTC time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use this:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1329429600)
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 16, 22, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pythons fromtimestamp gives you a localized date

If you want the UTC time, you'd like to use

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1329429600)
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 16, 22, 0)
```